# Tweak timeout period for socket connections on Windows CE

Tags: windows, sockets, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm testing how our software handles connection failures. We use `socket.BeginConnect` with a callback function set. The endpoint IP address and/or port number is deliberately invalid. The callback function gets called after ~21s every time (with timeout and connection failure, of course). I'd like to be able to tweak the timeout up or down for testing or final deployment.

According to [this MSDN article for Windows CE 5.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms884977.aspx), the key `HKLM\Comm\Tcpip\Parms\TcpInitialRTT` looks helpful. But I've tried the values 1, 2, 3 and 22 and the timeout does not change from ~21s. The computer was rebooted after each change.

Can the timeout for TCP/IP socket connections be tweaked at OS level? Using C# and .NET Compact Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You must do so using

```
IAsyncResult result = mysocket.BeginConnect(...)
```

then wait on the

```
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(yourtimeouthere, false);
```